# Vue router issue

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I have a link like below in a vue component file.

```
<li v-for="(word,index) in allWord" v-bind:key="index">
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'word', params: {id: word.id } }">
       {{word}}
    </router-link> 
</li>
```

My route settings in `index.js` file is like below

```
export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {   
            path: '/',          
            component: MainBody 
        },
        {   path: '/word/:id',
            name: 'word',   
            component: Word 
        }
    ]
});
```

I am getting URL like below

```
http://localhost:8080/word/4
```

I am trying to catch URL parameter in `word.vue` is like below

```
<script>
    export default {
        watch: {
            '$route': 'routeChanged'
        },
        methods: {
            routeChanged () {
                console.log(this.$route.params.id);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The issue is when I click on the `<li></li>` I am not getting any value in `console`, I am getting value when I click second time.

Why it is happening ? I would like to get value first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is caused by that fact that you are watching changes. To better understand this issue, here is a timeline:

1. User clicks "http://localhost:8080/word/4"
2. Vue router updates `$route`
3. Router view updates the view, swapping out `MainBody` for `Word`, updates the props passed and calls `created` and `mounted`

Since from the view of `word`, nothing has changed, it doesn't calls the watch

Manually parsing `$route` from any method isn't the cleanest solution, better is just to use the props in combination with the watcher to get your id:

```
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
             id: String,
        },
        created() {
             this.routeChanged();
        },
        watch: {
            'id': 'routeChanged',
        },
        methods: {
            routeChanged () {
                console.log(this.id);
            },
        },
    };
</script>
```

Make sure to specify `props: true` in your router if using this:

```
    {   path: '/word/:id',
        name: 'word',   
        component: Word,
        props: true,
    },
```

Comment: Thanks @Ferrtbig. Your solution is working properly. Thanks.

Comment: I am getting `route undefined` message when I first load `http://localhost:8080/`. Why it is printing ?

Comment: I wasn't clear in my answer, the `<script>` section should be added to `word.vue`, not `mainbody.vue`

Comment: Thanks @Ferrybig. I added `<script>` section to `word.vue`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to catch the value in the mounted() and updated().

```
methods: {
  getid: function()
  {
     this.wordid = this.$route.params.id
  } 
},

watch: {
  wordid: function(val) {
    console.log(this.wordid) // or console.log(val)
  }
},
mounted()
{
   this.getid()
},
updated()
{
 this.getid()
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Badgy. Your solution is working just my opposite. First time it is printing the `id` but not from second time.

Comment: @abuabu Ok sorry then for wasting your time with a wrong solution, im glad someone else had the right idea :)