# Invalid prop type from router params, expected Number got String

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I am trying to collect `id` value from URL.

Previously I take help in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51244073/vue-router-issue) post.

In my `index.js` of router file I have below code:

```js
{   path: '/word/:id',
    name: 'word',   
    component: Word,
    props: true,
},
```

In my component I have below code:

```html
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
             id: Number,
        },
        created() {
             this.routeChanged();
        },
        watch: {
            'id': 'routeChanged',
        },
        methods: {
            routeChanged () {
                console.log(this.id);
            },
        },
    };
</script>
```

I am getting below error:

> [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "id". Expected Number, got String.

Comment: @N.B. note that programming is not (only) about getting rid of error / warning messages. There are many legit reasons for not wanting to loosen your input prop type, and/or outsourcing casting to consumer / parent component.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That is the use case for Passing Props to Route Components with [Function mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#function-mode):

> You can create a function that returns props. This allows you to cast parameters into other types, combine static values with route-based values, etc.

In your case, instead of specifying the route option with `props: true`, you would pass a function to the `props` option:

```js
routes = [{
  path: '/word/:id',
  component: Word,
  props: castRouteParams
}];

function castRouteParams(route) {
  return {
    id: Number(route.params.id),
  };
}
```

Live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/8kyyw9w26l (click on the "Go to Test/3" link)

Comment: Thanks @ghybs. I am trying to use this value to fetch database value using an API. Now I am getting an URL like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/words/%E0%A6%86%E0%A6%A8-%E0%A6%A8%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%B8%E0%A6%BE` but this should be like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/words/2`. Thanks.

Comment: I do not understand your comment, sorry. But it looks like a different question to me.

Comment: @ghybs For curiosity purpose : Is there a way to set it to all routes at once ? With a little check for `id` presence in `route.params` to be sure maybe.

Comment: Hi @Ibris, you could probably apply a function on all route objects to rework the props member into such function mode. Please feel free to open a new question if necessary.